# Splinter find_by_css excluding a class item

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, splinter

class="conversation hasLabels read"

Hello, everyone, I am trying to access an unread email using a for loop and specifying a class

```py
browser.find_by_css(.conversation.hasLabels.hasAttachments)
```

The problem here is some emails have class="read" so when the for loop executes, it takes all the **read** ones also but that is a problem since the emails don't have an unread element. 
For better understanding, I would like to access a class providing exclusive parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently using the script this way grabs only what you ask so this solves my problem.

```py
browser.find_by_css('div[class="conversation hasLabels hasAttachments"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a :not

`.conversation.hasLabels.hasAttachments:not(.read)`

Answer (score 0):

It can help you if I understood the essence of the problem correctly:

```
browser.find_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class, "conversation")][contains(@class, "hasLabels")][not(contains(@class, "read"))]')
```